# 入力した内容を反映させたい・送信完了メッセージを表示したい

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML, CSS, javascriptで、VSCode, postmanを使い、あるシステムを作成しています。

以下の内容を実現したいのですがうまくいきません。

1. ページに入力した内容をそのまま反映させたい
2. その送信が完了したら送信完了メッセージを出したい

#### 1. ページに入力した内容をそのまま反映させたい

たぶんコードは合っているのですがなせか反映されない状態です。
（知人がDevToolsでやったら反映されていたらしいです。
なのでコードは合っているのかなと思います。キャッシュクリアや更新済みです）

#### 2. その送信が完了したら送信完了メッセージを出したい

POSTで送信はできているのでindex.jsの記述が誤っているのだと思うのですが
調べてもわからなかったのでお力添えのほどよろしくお願いします。

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script><br><br><br>

  <a href="food.html">好きな食べ物</a>
  <a href="profile.html">プロフィール</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**food.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  
  <a href="index.html">戻る</a><br><br><br><br>

    <form id="formId">
        　<br>
        <input type="text" name="food"><br>
        <input type="button" value="送信" onclick="changeAction()">
      </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
html {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**index.js**

```
function changeAction(){
  let food = "apple";
  
fetch('https~~~',{
  method: "POST",
  }),
}).then(x=>console.log(x))
}

//送信完了

fetch('https://~~~')
.then(res => {
  // TODO 送信完了メッセージを表示
  
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    alert('送信に成功しました。');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert("送信に失敗しました。");
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初に Python の wsgiref(Web Server Gateway Interface REFerence implementation) モジュールを使って、テスト用の簡素な HTTP サーバを作成します(8001番ポートを listen)。

**http_server.py**

```py
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import json

def server(environ, start_response):
  if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    wsgi_input = environ['wsgi.input']
    content_length = int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH'])
    data = json.loads(wsgi_input.read(content_length))

  status = '200 OK'
  headers = [
    ('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
    ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization'),
  ]

  start_response(status, headers)
  return (
    [json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')]
      if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'
      else [b''])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  PORT = 8001
  with make_server('', PORT, server) as httpd:
    print(f'Start simple http server on port {PORT}...')
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

`index.js` と `food.html` を以下の様に書き換えます。フォーム(`onsubmit` event と callback 関数)を使う必要性が感じられないので `button` の `onClick` event と callback 関数のみを指定しています。

**index.js**

```js
function changeAction(){
  const food = $('input[name="food"]').val();
  fetch('http://localhost:8001/', {
    method: "POST",
    body: '{"food":"' + food + '"}',
    mode: "cors",
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ~~~',
    }),
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('fail');
    }
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // 送信完了
    _showAlert('送信に成功しました。');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    _showAlert('送信に失敗しました。');
    console.error(error);
  });
}

function _showAlert(msg) {
  var $alert = $('<div>').prependTo($('#container')).addClass('alert');
  $alert.hide().text(msg).fadeIn(3000, function() {
    $alert.fadeOut(3000, function() {
      $alert.remove();
      $('input[name="food"]').val('');
    });
  });
}
```

**food.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="index.html">戻る</a><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <table align="center">
    <tr><td>好きな食べ物　</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="food"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="送信" onclick="changeAction()"></td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**実行結果**
[image: test]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。拝見させていただき、自分とは違うところを治しました。サーバーの違いからか”送信失敗しました。”と出てしまいます。また、appleと入れてもappleと出てこず、””と出てきてしまいます。。現在httpserverとpostmanを使っているのですがhttpserver は立て、HTML送信後、postmanのsendを押しています。プログラミング初心者で両方とも使うのが初めてでどちらが原因で送信に失敗しているのかわかりません。もしこれが原因なのかなと思うことがあれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: もしかして認証で失敗しているということはないでしょうか？ 回答のコードでいえば、`if (!res.ok) { ...` の直前に `console.log(res.status);` を入れて HTTP レスポンスのステータスコードを表示する様にしてみて下さい。認証エラーであれば `401` になっているかと思います。

Comment: HTTP レスポンスのステータスコードを表示してみました。画像を貼ってみたので見ていただきたいです。401エラーはありませんでした。。

Comment: こちら側にデータが来ることができていないということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、サーバが空(カラ)のデータを返しているので、こちらから送信しているデータの内容にサーバ側が対応していないのかもしれません。サーバ側での処理が具体的にどうなっているのか不明なので何とも言えませんが。。。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。サーバの事は私もわからないので先輩方に聞いてみようと思います。ご丁寧にありがとうございました。

Comment: ごめんなさい。一つ質問させてください。初期にHTTPサーバを立てているのを忘れていました。。その際はPOST受け取り用の記述をかいていないから動作していないのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その場合はサーバからのレスポンスを待ち続けてタイムアウトになっていたのではないかと思います。

Comment: 今、確認したら400と401エラーが出てしまっていました。POST受け取り用の記述を書いても、書かなくても出てしまいます。。キャッシュも削除したりしたのですが、、

Comment: 認証エラーと [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) なのであれば POST受け取りの処理以前の問題かと思いますが。。。

Comment: 400はキャッシュクリアすればいいと記事で見たのですがそれ以前ということでしょうか？

Comment: あとhttp~~~も確認しましたがあっていました。。

Comment: 今回は認証で `Authorization': 'Bearer ~~~'` という内容をサーバへ送信していると思われますが、これがサーバ側の仕様と合っていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、、あっています、、仕様書からコピーしているので、、再度確認したのですが、、汗

Comment: そのサーバの運用担当者にサーバのログを確認してもらう様に頼んでみてはどうでしょうか。実際に 400, 401 レスポンスコードが出ている以上、こちら側ではどうしようもないので。。。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。そうですね、確認してみます。

Answer (score 0):

> 2. その送信が完了したら送信完了メッセージを出したい

一つの例

```
function changeAction(){
    const ajaxs = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('piyo.html');
        if (response.ok) {
            const retValue = await response.text();
            return Promise.resolve(retValue);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('file not found');
        }
    }

    ajaxs()
        .then(function (ret){
            console.log(ret);
        })
        .catch(function (errs){
                console.log(errs);
            }
        );

}
```

追記、寒かったので動くコードを書いた。（明日、テストphpスクリプトを止めます。）

```js
function sends(){

        const ajax_1 = async () => {
        const formData =  new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("fm1"));

// 送信用データを設定
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: "cors",
                body: formData,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            };

            delete options.headers['Content-Type'];

            const response = await fetch('https://yyz.2-d.jp/res.php', options);

            if (response.ok) {
                const retValue = await response.text();
                return Promise.resolve(retValue);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject('file not found');
            }
        }

        ajax_1()
            .then(ret=>{
                alert('send ok!');
                console.log(ret);
            })
            .catch(errs=>{
                    console.log(errs);
                }
            );
　  return false;
    }
```

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<form name="fm1">
    Post data, please.　<br>
    ＆ DATA returns <br>
    <input type="text" name="food"><br>
    <input type="button" value="送信" onclick="sends()">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。いただいたコードでやってみたところ、送信完了しました、とメッセージがでてきてくれませんでした。　　　.await fetch('piyo.html');→await fetch('food.html');にも直してやってみたのですが、うまくいってくれませんでした。。

Comment: console.log(ret);の所に完了表示のスクリプトを書かないと表示されませんよ、適時修正して完成させてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。console.log('送信に成功しました。');　と修正しましたが変化はありませんでした。。

Comment: そもそも送信自体ができていないのかなと思い、console.log('送信に失敗しました。');とも編集してみたのですが、それも表示されませんでした、、

Comment: 簡単に動作確認するなら console.log(ret);の代わりに　alert('send ok!'); とか入れると良いかもしれません。

Comment: alert('send ok!');とやってみましたが、aleatも出てきてくれませんでした。教えていただいてるのに申し訳ないです。。そもそもPOST自体が送られていないのかとも思うのですが、、

Comment: 別サイトにアクセスしていてクロスオリジンになっていませんか？ https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: なってないと思います。。

Comment: 今、画面仕様の画像を貼ったのですが、console.logだとあれかなと思いalertに変えてみました。上司に聞いたところ
fetch('https://~~')
.then(res => {　の形でやってみてと言われました。それでこの形ならこう書くのかなと思い下記のようにやってみたのですが、適していないのか送信完了メッセージが出てきてくれません。添削してくださるとうれしいです。

Comment: fetch('https://~~')
.then(res => {
  // TODO 送信完了メッセージを表示
  
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    alert('送信に成功しました。');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert("送信に失敗しました。");
            }
        );